# Retrieval of the error counters via TIOCGICOUNT returns always error (-1)

Tags: linux, ioctl, ftdi

I have come across a show stopping problem when developing an interface application for a USB to RS422 converter module.

I need to retrieve the UART error counters for framing, overrun, parity and break errors. But the call to ioctl always returns -1 and the counter values from the retrieved struct are jumping to very big numbers.

The code i am using to retrieve the counters is the following:

```cpp
struct serial_icounter_struct counters;
int ret = ioctl(portDescriptor, TIOCGICOUNT, &counters);
```

To set the portDescriptor i am using a similar code to:

```cpp
int portDescriptor = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

struct termios new_port_settings;
//clear the new struct
memset(&new_port_settings, 0, sizeof(new_port_settings)); 

//set port settings
new_port_settings.c_cflag = B57600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
new_port_settings.c_oflag = 0;
new_port_settings.c_lflag = 0;
new_port_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
new_port_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

int error = tcsetattr(portDescriptor, TCSANOW, &new_port_settings)
```

Sometimes we also need to enable flow control or parity e.g.

```cpp
new_port_settings.c_cflag = new_port_settings.c_cflag | CRTSCTS;
```

I have tried the code on a Ubuntu 11.10 32bit and on a SLES11 SP1 64bit, both with the FTDI_SIO kernel module.

Is anybody aware of any kind of issue regarding the usage of TIOCGICOUNT or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The fact that `ioctl()` returns -1 suggests it probably never sets `counters` to anything, so the big numbers you see may just be garbage that happened to sit in memory before the call. You can try to zero out the struct before calling `ioctl()`. Have you checked `errno` after `ioctl()` returns?

Comment: Hi Adam, you are right the struct is not zeroed before the ioctl call and what we see is garbage. The errno returns 22 "Invalid argument". Which one fo the arguments do you think is referring to?

Comment: In this case the third argument is a pointer to a userland buffer which should be accepted. According to [manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) if the file descriptor was wrong `errno` would be EBADF or ENOTTY. It is probably the request (second arg) which it complains about. Perhaps it isn't supported by the driver? Could you check `dmesg` and try it out on other devices (an RS232 port for example rather than USB)?

Comment: I just encountered this. We are using a cp210x usb->serial chipset and the driver cannot handle the TIOCGICOUNT ioctl. This is a bummer because I spent 1/2 a day adding code to our project to query the statistics (looking for a BRK) but stopped cold because the device doesn't support this ioctl.