# Serial (UART) buffer overflow at high speed

Tags: linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspbian, uart

I'm trying to transmit data between 2 Raspberry Pi's (unidirectionally) with Raspbian via UART at 4Mbps. I'm using UART0 ([BCM2835 Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) page 175).

I have successfully configured the UART clock source so I am able to transmit/receive at such a high speed, and indeed it works. I can send bytes and receive them correctly at the other side.

However, if I try to do a continuous transfer of data, a few bytes are lost (~2%) so I guess I'm overflowing a buffer on reception (because up to 1Mbps, continuous transmission works fine).

As far as I know, there are two buffers on reception, the hardware buffer which in case of Raspberry Pi's UART0 is 16 bytes and the software buffer on main memory. Kernel moves data from hardware buffer to software buffer and my application takes data from there.

Is there any way to know which of those two buffers overflowed? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: The hardware buffer is probably overflowing. At 4 Mbps, it fills up every 32 **microseconds**; servicing that reliably is tough.

Comment: But, is there any way to prove it? Any FLAG or similar? By the way, since it's 8N1, there are 10 bits per byte (8 + 1 start + 1 stop) so I think it would take ~40 microseconds for the buffer to fill up. Not very different from 32, though. Thanks.

Comment: Try using the **TIOCGICOUNT** ioctl() on the open serial port file descriptor.  Among the counter stats are receive overruns and buffer overruns.  But one user reports difficulty in using that ioctl(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791813/retrieval-of-the-error-counters-via-tiocgicount-returns-always-error-1

Answer (score 3):

The issue got solved for me by using `Hardware Flow Control (CTS & RTS)`. At higher speeds, you must need to use the `HSUART (UART with DMA capabilities)`. If your `serial-port` supports `16550A` or similar, you can configure `CONFIG_8250`, `CONFIG_DW`, `CONFIG_DMA` in your linux kernel and start using `DMA-capable UART`. I have been working on `High-Speed UART (HSUART)` with `baud rates` as high as `3M/4M`  using `h/w flow control` without any issues.